# LowerCase and upperCase in Strings

Tags: java

Here is my class for finding the amount of spaces, amount of vowels and amount of consonants in a sentence.  It works fine but i need it to ignore the cases.  How do i do this? I am familiar with the "ignore case" code but im not sure where to put it in this particular program.

```
            public class Counting{
            private String sentence;
            private int spaces;
            private int vowels;
            private int consonants;


            public Counting(){
                sentence = new String();
                spaces = 0;
                vowels = 0;
                consonants = 0;

            }

            public void setSentence(String sentence){
                this.sentence = sentence;
            }

            public void compute(){
                for(int i =0; i < sentence.length();i++){
                    char letter = sentence.charAt(i);
                        if(sentence.charAt(i)==' ' ){
                            spaces++;

                            }
                        else if((letter=='a')||(letter=='e')
                                 ||(letter=='i')||(letter=='o')||(letter=='u'))
                                    vowels++;

                        else{
        consonants++;
        }
        }
                            }

            public int getSpaces(){
                 return spaces;
            }

            public int getVowels(){
    return vowels;
        }
public int getConsonants(){
    return consonants;
            }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

A common way to do this is to simply convert the original string to all lower case.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string passed to your class to lower case:

```
        public Counting(){  
            setSentence("");
            spaces = 0;
            vowels = 0;
            consonants = 0;

        }

        public void setSentence(String sentence){
            this.sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
        }
```

Comment: This is not very good practice because you might need the original sentence later in the code. But it's a good starting idea: having `this.sentence = sentence.toLowerCase(); this.lowerCaseSentence = sentence.toLowerCase()` seems much better.

Comment: stackular I put it in this method.  The set Method(). And yeah it works a ttreat.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
letter.equalsIgnoreCase("a")
```

for checks the `letter` is `A` or `a`

Comment: Note that the comparison is against the String "a", not the char 'a'.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier to just maintain a set of all vowels, and consonants and include upper and lower cases - your code as is will include numbers and punctuation as consonants

```
if (consonents.contains(c)) consonents++;
else if (vowels.contains(c)) vowels++;
else if (spaces.contains(c)) spaces++
```

alternatively you could keep a map of char and property (an enum starting at 0 and incremented by 1 and including misc as a catch all) and then just keep an array of property counts:

```
counts[property.get(c)]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in your `compute()` method. This is not very efficient, but it's the simplest thing to do.

```
public void compute() {
    String lowerCaseSentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
    //...
}
```

And replace `sentence` with `lowerCaseSentence` in the rest of the code in `compute()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The best way is to convert the whole input sentence into upper case or Lower case and carry out the required operations on it

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
sentence.toLowerCase();
```